# slideshow using mouse scrolling to change image

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, slideshow

I'm trying to achieve this kind of effect for an images slideshow :

http://blackberryjournal.tumblr.com/

I can't find any informations about this, even can nammed it to search about it on the net...

it seems to use background-image. but i can't find any css modifications when scrolling.

there's a parent div,

and then inside the div this html, one table "post photo" per photo:

```
<table class="post photo" style="background-image:url(http://36.media.tumblr.com/cf5e715f0f818e0329fabe1f5a70f326/tumblr_n9qe04jhFh1rqy89io1_1280.jpg)" alt="mmm artisanal">
    <tr>
        <td class="caption"><p>mmm artisanal</p></td>
        <td class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
            <span><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/reblog/93676683910/rMP2KlVN" class="reblog_button"style="display: block;width:20px;height:20px;"></a></span>
            <span><div class="like_button" data-post-id="93676683910" id="like_button_93676683910"></div></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="post photo" style="background-image:url(http://36.media.tumblr.com/dd3f10db409b054f132bc7a3de4e8bc2/tumblr_n9qdx4JN7s1rqy89io1_1280.jpg)" alt="Amaury">
    <tr>
        <td class="caption"><p>Amaury</p></td>
        <td class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
            <span><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/reblog/93676603605/rmk5COGb" class="reblog_button""></a></span>
            <span><div class="like_button" data-post-id="93676603605" id="like_button_93676603605"></div></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

can anybody help me with this ?
anyone knows if it uses a jquery plugin ? or a way to do it ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: It's implementation is rather easy, you only need to copy the required CSS and the JS part that initializes it, which can be found in the page ;). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/0hd2k2jf/

Comment: You've got `</td>` closing tags instead of `</tr>` before `</table>`

Comment: thanks @TasosK. i tottaly forgot to check for js inside the pages... i was loking for an external file !